# AL compile in cmd dont work but works in vs code

Tags: dynamics-business-central, dynamics-al

I have a problem when i call the al compiler from the cmd. Im getting the dotnet errors. But when im uses the built in ctrl + shift + b in vs code, it will compile and create an .app files

this is my script:

```
C:\Users\dsda\.vscode\extensions\ms-dynamics-smb.al-11.5.834620\bin\alc.exe /project:. /packagecachepath:./.alpackages/ /out:test.app
```

This is only some of the errors:

```
Objects\CodeUnits\AppTaskManagement.Codeunit.al(1826,14): error AL0185: DotNet 'Uri' is missing
Objects\CodeUnits\AppTaskManagement.Codeunit.al(1827,17): error AL0185: DotNet 'HttpResponseMessage' is missing
Objects\CodeUnits\AppTaskManagement.Codeunit.al(1828,31): error AL0185: DotNet 'HttpClient' is missing
Objects\CodeUnits\AppTaskManagement.Codeunit.al(1829,20): error AL0185: DotNet 'MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue' is missing
Objects\CodeUnits\AppTaskManagement.Codeunit.al(1831,30): error AL0185: DotNet 'HttpResponseMessage' is missing
```

ssdsadasdasdas sadasdsad

Comment: I have changed my script to this and now it works

```
C:\Users\sadasd\.vscode\extensions\ms-dynamics-smb.al-11.5.834620\bin\alc 
/project:C:\Users\asdsadasd\test\example\app 
/packagecachepath:C:\Users\asdsadasdsa\test\example\app\.alpackages 
/target:internal 
/assemblyProbingPaths:C:/Windows/assembly/ 
/errorlog:C:\Users\asdsadas\test\example\app\error.log
```

Comment: You can add this info into an Answer and mark it as Accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed my script to this and now it works

```
C:\Users\sadasd\.vscode\extensions\ms-dynamics-smb.al-11.5.834620\bin\alc /project:C:\Users\asdsadasd\test\example\app /packagecachepath:C:\Users\asdsadasdsa\test\example\app\.alpackages /target:internal /assemblyProbingPaths:C:/Windows/assembly/ /errorlog:C:\Users\asdsadas\test\example\app\error.log
```